# Where is the build log located in Team Foundation Server 2010?

Tags: tfs, build

I am looking for the physical location of the TFS workflow log. Not the MSBuild Log but the log you see when you click "View Log".

I have read in other forums that the log is stored in an SQL database. But which database is it and specifically what table?

Thanks. Hope someone knows the answer to this.

Comment: This information is not stored in a file.

Answer (score 2):

The entire build log can be found in the **Tfs_YourTeamProjectCollection** database in the **Tbl_BuildInformation**. The **Tbl_BuildInformation** table contains self referencing entries to preserve the build log hierarchy, and all the build information is saved in XML. The information is saved as different node types which correspond to different build activities.

If you are interested in going down that route, I go into a little more detail in my [***blog***](http://paulselles.wordpress.com/2013/11/15/tfs-build-log-querying-build-log-data/). It is a bit much to post here.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the log file by using the TFS web access link.  See this MSDN post for more details.  I just used this trick and it was fantastic.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsbuild/thread/14ce49ea-f61a-45e2-be32-beffc81ce415?prof=required

> Another way to view the log is via the web access(right click on the build output tab and choose "copy full path" and paste it onto a browser) and the log does get downloaded so you can scroll down quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The build log is a different view of the full which by default can be found under the [build location][Build name]\logs directory.

You can retrieve the list of log locations from the database by querying `tbl_Build` table in the `Tfs_<CollectionName>` database, e.g.:

```
   SELECT [BuildId],[StartTime],[FinishTime],[LogLocation]
   FROM [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_Build]
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer but I'm looking for the location of the log when you click "View Log", not MSBuild log. MSBuild log is outputted to a text file while the contents of "View Log" isn't. My colleague says it is stored in an sql database, it may be in Tfs_Warehouse. Do you have any idea where it might be?

Comment: No, I'm not aware of any another location other than the file system.

Comment: I would like an answer to this one too... I know this is an old question, but the log really should be accessible someplace other than a web browser. :\