# Where can I find the inner exception of a canceled/aborted TFS build?

Tags: tfs

Sometimes, when running builds with TFS 2012, we get the following error:

> The workflow instance has been canceled. (Reason: An error occurred while calling tracking participants causing the instance to be aborted.  See the inner exception for more details.)

It can happen anytime during the build. We've looked for that 'inner exception' in the build log, in Diagnostics final logs, in test results, in Windows event logs... but we've found nothing. There is a missing try/catch block somewhere, maybe?

---

UPDATE:

As we could not find anything more about this error, we finally removed and created again the build controller and its agents. After that, the problem has gone and the build is even faster.

---

UPDATE 2:

The error came back a couple of weeks later and the build is slower again...

Comment: I am not giving you this as an answer as it may be wrong.  I have not worked with TFS 2012 for many years now but if memory serves me correctly, the difference between 2010 and 2012 for a lot of things was the same.  Look at this post about the build logs for 2010 and you may find the logs for your 2012
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697631/where-is-the-build-log-located-in-team-foundation-server-2010

Answer (score 0):

For this situation, you may go the SQL route.  However, it's not recommended to operate the TFS database, if you really want to operate the database, please make a backup first.

> All the build log information is available on the Project Collection
>   Database where the data is recorded one activity at a time so we are
>   able to query all the way up to the current build activity. All this
>   data can be found in the SQL Database, appropriately named
>   `Tfs_YourTeamProjectCollection`, table `Tbl_BuildInformation`; where
>   YourTeamProjectCollection is the name of your Team Project Collection.
>   The build activity will appear as independent XML nodes, divided up
>   into 16 different types.

More details please refer this blog: [Tfs Build Log: Querying Build Log Data](https://paulselles.wordpress.com/2013/11/15/tfs-build-log-querying-build-log-data/)

---

Update

If you are using some custom activities and cause the issue. To diagnose problems caused by custom build process activities, or by uncaught exceptions, you could also try to debug the build process on your build server. Check [Debug a build process on the build server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635150.aspx#Check%20your%20build%20system%20and%20debug%20your%20build%20process) for more info.

Besides, you could also try to use some 3-party analysis tools for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks to both (@JasonH). We had read that post last week and did not find anything but the same message as in other logs.

Comment: @mikefonted Diagnostics log, event log , log in data base, almost all the way up. If you are using some custom activities and cause the issue. To diagnose problems caused by custom build process activities, or by uncaught exceptions, you could also try to debug the build process on your build server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635150.aspx#Check your build system and debug your build process Besides, you could also try to use some 3-party analysis tool for troubleshooting.